# Make a text in UILabel a link

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a `UILabel`.

I have connected it and passing a value of string to it and it is showing as text correctly.

So, in this string how can I add a link to a word? In web we use `<a href="link"></a>`, but for Swift,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UITextView and select Detection for Links, Phone Numbers and other things in the inspector.